# Not following data validation rules during copy paste event in excel

Tags: excel, vba

In this macro enabled sheet i have data validations for columns where i want to regulate the data input. The problem i am facing here is that, Considering scenario where the customer wishes to copy data from another excel file. Implementing this scenario i have copied some data from a foreign excel to my data validations enabled sheet. I have a column where the user can input only text length less than 9 but when i copy the data say text length greater than 9, such scenarios do not seem to show any error message. Is there a workaround which would help me overcome this situation?

Comment: There is no data validation check if you copy/paste a value into a cell that has data validation. • It's the same if you put a data validation onto a cell that has already data in it (then it won't check the data too). Data validation is only checked if you write data manually (by user action). Even putting in data with VBA doesn't trigger the data validation.

Comment: Not a data validation as such. But how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: I posted an alternative way to the built in Data Validation. It is more complicated but can handle copy/paste actions.

Answer (score 4):

#### A workaround since Data Validation doesn't work with copy/paste

Remove Excel's data validation and replace it with your own validation could be a solution to your issue.

This allows you to perform your own validation checks. And if non-valid data was inserted we just `.Undo` the insert action. So only completely valid data can be inserted.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    'rule 1: column A allows only text length up to 9
    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A"))
    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In AffectedCells
            If Not Len(Cell.Value) <= 9 Then 'check length of each cell
                MsgBox "The data """ & Cell.Value & """ inserted in " & Cell.Address & " in column A was longer than 9. We undo!", vbCritical
                Application.Undo 'undo insert
                Exit Sub 'stop checking after one invalid data was found.
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
    
    'rule 2: column B allows only …
    'Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("B:B"))
    'If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
       'to be continued as above …
    
    
End Sub
```

#### Note that the solution above has one big disadvantage

The validation ranges are hard coded in the VBA code. If you eg set a validation rule for column C and then you insert a column before that column C it will move to D but the validation rules still apply to C.

To avoid this issue you can use [Named Ranges](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) instead of hard coded ranges. So you define a range in your sheet and eg. name it `Rule1` (better choose a meaningful name instead of numbering rules). For example mark column C and give it a name.

Then you can use that name in …

```
Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("Rule1"))
```

… and now the rules will stick to the named range and you can insert and move your ranges as you like.

Comment: Good solution with `Intersect`and `Undo`! As my simple `Select Case Target.Address` suggestion would only work if exactly 1 cell is pasted, I'll delete my answer :)

Comment: Can you help me with data validation for decimal data? For example, A column should contain numeric of length 9 with 2 decimal positions.

Comment: @ThanujaReddy Can you please post it as a new question? Include the code you already have tried and tell where you got stuck. The problem here is we cannot answer that in comments and the original question is already answered. So just open up a new one.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have posted a new question with the code i have tried. The link to the question is as follows: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511137/decimal-data-validation-using-macros) Please take a look.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ there is an issue with this code. Suppose if i copy a set of data from another excel sheet, A part of the data may  not follow the condition for data validation. In this scenario the usage of this code undo's all the data including the data which follows the condition. How can we overcome this?

Comment: @BtR No. There is no selective undo. So it can only do a complete undo and tell the user to get his data completely valid before pasting so only completly valid data can be paseted. • If you need to select only valid data out of a source you would need a completely different approach where VBA validates the source data first and copy only valid data with VBA (so VBA copies, not the user). But note that you should notify the user wich invalid data was **not** copied otherwise the user will not notice that he "loses" data during the process.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Can you please educate me on the "VBA validating the source data first and copy the valid data" with an example scenario?

Comment: @This cannot be answered in a comment, and asking that as a question would be off-topic. Try it on your own, if you get stuck post your code and ask a new question to it. You would try to do something like that: Loop through your source data, validate each row/cell if it is not valid delete it and copy the rest, or if it is valid copy only the valid ones. Still I recommend to mark the invalid ones for the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Excel. Data validation does not work if the user pastes a value into the cell.

What you can do, however, is mitigate against pasting at least by using Ctrl+v. Enter the following into the ThisWorkbook module in the VBA Editor:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^v", ""
End Sub
 
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^v"
End Sub
```

This makes it so that when you activate the workbook, Ctrl+v is set to do nothing. Then if you're working with multiple workbooks and want to use Ctrl+v elsewhere, the behaviour is reset to normal when you deactivate this workbook.

Comment: Consider the scenario where the data inflow is huge. In this case copy paste is the only option.

Comment: Data validation was never designed to work with users copying & pasting huge amounts of data from external sources. If your method relies on users doing this, I would suggest scrapping validation, but using Conditional Formatting: for example you could highlight a cell in red where the value falls outside your parameters, in order to manually flag to the user that something is not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue, my solution was to use conditional formatting instead. Conditional formatting can highlight cells if they contain text that does not appear in my 'data validation' list.

The easiest way I have found is using the match function. My formula looks like this:

```
=IF($C1="",FALSE,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C1,'Validation Lists'!$A:$A,0))))
```

Where

`$C1` is the first cell in the column I want to highlight

`'Validation Lists'!$A:$A` contains the list of values I want to allow

To apply conditional formatting:

highlight the range you want to have conditional formatting > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a Formula to determine which cells to format