# Decimal data validation using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enabled work sheet in which i have data validations for columns where i want to regulate the data input. I cannot use regular data validation feature in excel as it fails to function as we copy data from other sources which is the case in my requirement.So i am implementing data validations through macros . I have a scenario where one column can input only decimal data. The conditions are as follows the input data is of length 9 which constitutes only 2 decimal positions. I have partly written a macro for this validation which does not work(When i make a invalid input macro is not triggered therefore no msgbox pop up) and i am stuck at this point.Please help me out here to find a different if condition for the validation. The macro i have written is as follows:

```
Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("F:F"))

If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then

For Each Cell In AffectedCells
        If Not (Cell.Value * (10 ^ 2) Mod 10) <> 0 Then

            MsgBox "The value you entered is not valid." 

            Application.Undo 'undo insert
            Exit Sub 'stop checking after one invalid data was found.
        End If
```

Comment: Define does not work - what doesn't work? Does this give you an error? Does your excel crash? Does it run and give you unexpected results? Does it run and nothing happens?

Comment: Can you give us some sample inputs? Do you just want to make sure the inputs are in the format of `#######.##`?

Comment: You have to be careful with the use of `If Not (Cell.Value * (10 ^ 2) Mod 10) <> 0 Then`. Entering say `123456789` can result in overflow error. Also what should happen if someone enters say `123.45` or `123456789` or `12345.1234`

Comment: @urdearboy does not work meaning - When i give inputs such as 12.9999 or other invalid inputs the message is not triggered.

Comment: @SiddharthRout the user is allowed to enter any input which is greater than 10000000. As i have mentioned in the question, the places before decimal point cannot exceed length 7 and after decimal point should have length 2. Adding the entire length of the input to 9. I hope this clarifies your doubt. Please help me figure out a way to overcome this problem.

Comment: @urdearboy Some sample inputs would be 1111.78 , 123.67, 127888.89 , 12.999(this input should trigger error message as it contains 3 decimal positions), 12.89, 45.56, 12345678.09(this input should trigger error message as the number before decimal is of length 8). Consider this the sample space.

Comment: So 12.89 is ok. i.e length before the decimal can be less than 8. One last question, if the length before the decimal is more than 8?

Comment: As i have already mentioned in the above comment, it should trigger an error message for which i have not written any code.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. I have the code ready but before I post, I need to clear the doubt. Is 12.43 correct? Is 123456789.12 correct? is 123.3456 correct? I know that 1234.1234 is incorrect

Comment: The input should contain 2 decimal positions. And the number before decimal point should not exceed 7 digits. so 12.43 is correct. 123456789.12 is not valid. 123.3456 is not valid.

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be pasted on the sheet code space for the sheet you want the macro to run on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xCell As Range, AffectedCells As Range

Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("F:F"))

If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
    For Each xCell In AffectedCells
            If Not (xCell.Value * (10 ^ 2) Mod 10) <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "The value you entered is not valid."
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                        Application.Undo
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
    Next xCell
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This answer is not working for me. I have tried various inputs within the given range.I have tried different permutations of entries but none of them trigger the message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you should not have a problem undrstanding it. But if you do then simply ask.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range, AffectedCells As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set AffectedCells = Intersect(Target, Columns(6))

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each xCell In AffectedCells
            '~~> Avoid cases like IP address 10.1.2.234
            '~~> Check if the number contains decimal
            If IsNumeric(xCell.Value) And _
            Int(xCell.Value) <> xCell.Value Then
                '~~> Check the position of the decimal
                '~~> Check the length of the string
                If Mid(xCell.Value, Len(xCell.Value) - 2, 1) <> "." Or _
                Len(xCell.Value) > 9 Then
                    '
                    '~~> INVALID INPUT: Do what you want
                    '

                    'MsgBox "The value you entered is not valid."
                    'Application.Undo
                    'Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next xCell
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```